# Excel Advanced Filter not doing anything

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter my test database by writing a small macro, And I am not sure why it's not working.
It doesn't do anything at all, even when I try to do the same thing with Data -> Advanced Filter.
My data which I am trying to filter:

[image]

I am trying to filter in the same sheet. The place where criteria is:

[image]

Place where I am trying to copy: [image]

AE3:AT3 will get the values and then these will be change the criteria range with if formulae. AD6:AU6 is where I want to paste filtered data

The macro which I am using:

```
    Sub Filterme()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheet1.Range("AZ2:BO3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet1.Range("AD6:AU6"), Unique:=False
    End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use `Sheet1.Range("AZ2").CurrentRegion` and `Sheet1.Range("AD6").CurrentRegion`. Keep in mind that the first row has to contain the headers. Also, if you have not already, watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YNhxVu2a5s).

Comment: Even after doing the change, the macro did not do anything

Comment: Since all your Criteria headers have a value, then if a single header is wrong in Criteria Range, you won't get any results. On the other hand, if you remove the `*`-s, you will get the results if the wrong header has no value, but then you won't know if a header is wrong. To use my code replace the my values `A3, A11, A16` with your values `A1,AZ2,AD6`.

Answer (score 0):

### Advanced Filter Example

This solution is based on [Paul Kelly](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/)'s [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YNhxVu2a5s).

[image]
[image]
[image]

- Check if the headers are the same in all three ranges.
- To use the following code, just replace my values `A3,A11,A16` with
  your values `A1,AZ2,AD6`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterMe()
    Const Proc As String = "FilterMe"
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    Const src As String = "A3"
    Const cri As String = "A11"
    Const cop As String = "A16"

    ' Define ranges.
    Dim Source As Range, Criteria As Range, CopyTo As Range
    With Sheet1
        Set Source = .Range(src).CurrentRegion
        Set Criteria = .Range(cri).CurrentRegion
        Set CopyTo = .Range(cop).CurrentRegion
    End With

    ' Apply filter.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Source.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Criteria, CopyToRange:=CopyTo, Unique:=False

CleanExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
           , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo CleanExit
End Sub
```